# Fullcalendar with view more button Uncaught TypeError

Tags: events, fullcalendar, typeerror, appointment

I found an api for restricting a limited number of events per day which shows a "view more" button. I implemented that tool like in the description on github but get the following error message every time:

```
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appointments' of null**
```

In addition the events in the calendar will be shown at the top in the cells of the weekdays...

Maybe some of you could solve this problem anytime and can help me, because I couldn't find an appropriate post on stackoverflow or somewhere else.